# Declare Drop Down List with pre values in Umbraco v 7.4

Tags: c#, data-binding, enums, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to find out how to declare Drop Down List with pre values in Umbraco v 7.4.
I have the following Enum:

```
public enum Gender
        {
            Male = 1,
            Female = 2,
            Transgender = 3
        }
```

I need to the best way to bind the DDL with this enum pre values (in code behind).

Thanks in advance for all helpers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the community package called [Nupickers](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nupickers/), they have a property editor called [Enum DropDown Picker](https://github.com/uComponents/nuPickers/wiki/Property-Editor-Enum-DropDown-Picker).